A message I bcc'd myself disappeared from my Gmail inbox
I recently sent someone an email from my Gmail account and bcc'd myself on the email. However, the message completely disappeared from my inbox a short time later. I know I didn't accidentally delete it because it's not in the Trash folder. It's not in my Spam folder or the archives either. I also highly doubt someone would go through the trouble of hacking into my Google account just to delete a single message. I had to use Outlook to copy the message from my sent folder back to my inbox to "recover" it (as Gmail doesn't offer a native means to duplicate a message).
Is there a way to figure out what exactly happened? I've seen audit logs mentioned on some help pages, but it seems that feature is only available for Google Workspace and not personal Gmail accounts.

Any message received from an address associated with your Gmail account including aliases will show in the Sent folder. This can't be undone.
Inbox, however,  is a label that is removed if a message is archived.  All messages including those not in the Inbox can be found in the "All Mail" folder. In your case it would always be in the Sent folder as well.
The fact that you could "move" the message from the Sent folder to the Inbox indicates the message was Archived.
Since you inserted "Outlook" into your question it may be the culprit if you are using it to access your Gmail account via IMAP.  Outlook may have removed the Inbox label based on your actions or some native behavior.
You are probably better placed that we are to figure out how the message got archived based on the way you use Gmail and Outlook desktop.

I did check the "All Mail" folder and found the message was missing the "Inbox" label. This was not the case for all the other emails I sent today. I do suspect Outlook may be the culprit.

Yes, When you send FROM yourself TO (or CC/BCC) yourself, the message will always show in your INBOX and SENT.  To remove the INBOX label it would require explicit action within Gmail (automatically via mail filter or manually by you), or by an external app/tool with access to the account (e.g. IMAP, API, etc.).
